# What does "Because" by itself mean?

Tags: meaning

The following depicts a real conversation between my housemate and myself a few years ago. (I'm happy to say I no longer live with him.)

Me: "I can't study when there's music playing."

He: "Okay, I'll turn it down a little bit."

Me: "Why can't you wear headphones?"

He: "Because."

What is the last sentence supposed to mean?

Comment: The meaning is context-sensitive, but usually it's either ***Because I say so*** or ***Because that's just the way it is***. Possibly in your case ***Because I don't like wearing headphones***.

Comment: Victor Hugo said "Parce que. Cette réponse de celui qui ne sait rien est aussi la réponse de celui qui sait tout", what gives "*Because. This answer from one who knows nothing is also the response from one who knows everything*".

Comment: It's claiming there's a reason, and I can't or won't say what it is.

Comment: This is probably the same in your language.

Comment: An adult may answer an annoying child's question like this: _Why_ can't I have an ice-cream? Because!

Comment: @Graffito - I was once watching TF1 (French TV) news (le JT 13h) and there was an item about things you could do in London, including a 'Charles Dickens tour'. The commentator helpfully told the viewers that Dickens was _le Victor Hugo anglais_. I had never before thought of either as the transmanche counterpart of the other.

Comment: Why was my question downvoted? Is it really inappropriate for the ELL forum?

Comment: @Thomas I see nothing particularly wrong with your question, so I've up voted it and voted to leave it open. As an asside. "Because?" can also be a one word question.  **"I don't like wearing headphones" "Because?" "They are uncomfortable"** It usually asks for clarification of a previous statement.

Answer (score 2):

“Because” by itself is an intentional non-answer.  Think of it as short for “Because I don't feel like it” or “Because I said so.”

Your housemate was implying that he didn't owe you an explanation for not wearing headphones; he simply refused to wear them.

Answer (score 1):

It does not **convey anything** specifically, but it has a colloquial meaning. It is the equivalent of a shrug:

[image]

This 'Because' is used almost in an ironic manner, not to provide any real reason. This particular usage is far more common in younger generation and exclusively casual, so there is no formal basis for just saying 'Because' as an answer to any question. For example:

> A: Why are you so stubborn?!
>
> B: Because.

Note: *It is not a short form or omitted form of a longer sentence and it certainly does not serve to provide a reason like "I don't like wearing headphones".*

Comment: At least have the `decency` to explain your downvotes please, rather than getting triggered. Thanks in advance.